# How to generate unto n digit combinations of an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to create a program in python which generates all the possible combinations (non-repeating) for a given number

If the input is "123", Output should be

```
123,132,213,231,312,321

12,13,21,23,31,32

1,2,3
```

My current code is

```py
    import itertools
    
    a=[1,2,3]
        
    for i in range(1,len(a)+1):
        print(list(itertools.combinations(a,i)))
```

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: Post the code you have written.

Comment: What does this print out when you run it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `itertools.permutations`:

```py
import itertools

def permute_all(value):
    return [''.join(permutation) for i in range(len(value)) for permutation in itertools.permutations(value, i+1)]
    
print(permute_all('123'))
# Outputs ['1', '2', '3', '12', '13', '21', '23', '31', '32', '123', '132', '213', '231', '312', '321']
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the non repeating all possible combinations and output.

```py
from itertools import permutations
N = str(int(input()))
for length in range(len(N),0,-1):
    currOrder = []
    for order in permutations(N,length):
        comb = ''.join(order)
        if comb not in currOrder:
            currOrder.append(comb)
    print(*currOrder,sep=",")
```